# How do I escape the '@' symbol inside a string literal key for a jmespath search query

Tags: python-3.x, jmespath

I am using jmespath to search a snippet of JSON, and one of the JSON keys contains an '@' symbol.  Since the '@' symbol is a reserved character, jmespath chokes.  I have tried a number of things to escape the '@' symbol unsuccessfully.  How do I escape the '@' symbol in my jmespath search?

Example:

```py
json = {"@name": "Bob", "address": "123 Main St"}

jmespath.search("@name", json)
```

Error message:

> {ParseError} Unexpected token: name: Parse error at column 1, token "name" (UNQUOTED_IDENTIFIER), for expression:
>   "@name"
>    ^

I have also tried the following variations for the above jmespath query, with the same error:

```py
jmespath.search("!@name", json)
```

```py
jmespath.search("\@name", json)
```

```py
jmespath.search("`@`name", json)
```

```py
jmespath.search("\"@\"name", json)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the correct way to escape it:

```py
jmespath.search("\"@name\"", json)
```

In my experience with JMESPath, some attributes from an object need to be double-quoted, for example, if I have an object `{"0": "txt", "name": "txt2"}`, I can access the name value with this command `@.name` but for a `0` value I need to put double quotes around the zero.  I can't do this `@.0` (it doesn't work), but adding double quotes works `@."0"`.  This is probably why JMESPath doesn't allow double quotes to define a string.  So this is the same case where you put certain special characters in an attribute.  In Python, the query is already a string, so you need to add additional quotes and escape the inner quotes `\"` to solve this problem.

In JavaScript, you can achieve the same result with `'"@name"'`.

Comment: Nicely done; note that `'"@name"'` works in Python too.